# Can't request from http server via Node

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, axios

I am trying to learn the Visual Code / Node / Typescript stack, and wanted to write some code which makes a GET request from a web server. I have tried using three different libraries: Axios, Node-Promise, and fetch(), and get the same affect.

When I run:

```
(<my http request>)
.then( (response) => {
    <- breakpoint ->
})
.catch (error) => {
    <- breakpoint ->
})
.finally(() => {
    <- breakpoint ->
});

next-statement;
```

... neither of the breakpoints are hit, and it goes directly to next-statement.

The fact that all three libraries fail suggests that there is something one with my Node config, Visual Code config, or even my PC. Or could it be becuase my application is running synchronously from the body of the main typescript module.

[Edit]
Well, it looks as if things are more complicated. The following chunk:

```
axios.get('http://www.google.co.uk')
.then((response) => {
    myStuff = response;
})
.catch((error) => {
    myError = error;
})
```

At the top level typescript module, not in a function, this actually works. However, if I put this code into a method called from a class's constructor, this, the code only runs after the top level code has finished running.

Comment: Why not show us <your http request>? Did you try console.log'ing something in then, catch and finally to rule out your breakpoints not being brokenpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe response takes too much time? Try to fetch google.com, and say what is the result.

Comment: Funnily enough, I tried doing exactly that!

Comment: Have you tried to create pure node.js file with this code, and test it alone?

Comment: Hi - I didn't use a JS file - just a pure typescript file. As I have added to the question, it works at the top level.